# How to use h.264 Reference Software to extract motion vectors in Python

Tags: python, video, vector, h.264, motion

I'm trying to decode an h.264 video so that I can access the motion vectors. I found the reference software:

http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/download/

but I'm having difficulty implementing this in python to parse out the relevant data that I want. What is a good way to approach this problem?

Comment: What difficulty are you having?

Comment: Well I'm completely new to video encoding / decoding. I need the motion vectors for a computer vision project, but I've never worked with h.264 standards before. Having difficulty starting in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing H.264 in Python can be done, but it's usually not the best tool for the job. If you really do want to use it you should start with the H.264 standard, not the reference software, although having both to hand is useful.

As I said Python isn't well suited to decoding video so there isn't much out there to help you. I have used it in the past to get or change the odd parameter and wrote a module ([bitstring](http://scott-griffiths.github.io/bitstring/)) to help. There is an example of parsing a H.264 structure in the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/examples.html):

This example creates a class that parses a structure that is part of the H.264 video standard.

```
class seq_parameter_set_data(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        """Interpret next bits in BitString s as an SPS."""
        # Read and interpret bits in a single expression:
        self.profile_idc = s.read('uint:8')
        # Multiple reads in one go returns a list:
        self.constraint_flags = s.readlist('4*uint:1')
        self.reserved_zero_4bits = s.read('bin:4')
        self.level_idc = s.read('uint:8')
        self.seq_parameter_set_id = s.read('ue')
        if self.profile_idc in [100, 110, 122, 244, 44, 83, 86]:
            self.chroma_format_idc = s.read('ue')
            if self.chroma_format_idc == 3:
                self.separate_colour_plane_flag = s.read('uint:1')
            self.bit_depth_luma_minus8 = s.read('ue')
            self.bit_depth_chroma_minus8 = s.read('ue')
            # etc.

>>> s = BitStream('0x6410281bc0')
>>> sps = seq_parameter_set_data(s)
>>> print(sps.profile_idc)
100
>>> print(sps.level_idc)
40
>>> print(sps.reserved_zero_4bits)
0b0000
>>> print(sps.constraint_flags)
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: What makes Python not good for video decoding? Just lack of prior work? I found this package called PyFFMPEG that I thought I would start with. What do you think? https://mhaller.github.io/pyffmpeg/

Comment: Python is too high level (and fundamentally too slow) to be good at decoding video natively. PyFFMPEG is just a Python wrapper around compiled decoder libraries which were probably written in C/C++. So it will give you the decoded video frames but not give any low-level detail about motion vectors etc. So there's very little prior work in Python decoding video as it would not be practical to use it to watch video!

Comment: Ok. good to know! I'm going to just find a program to output motion vectors from a video into a CSV or something similar, and then feed this into MATLAB and run my algorithmic work from there. thanks for the help